# Prove that for any $\epsilon > 0$, $\mathbb{P}\left (\frac{S_n}{n} > p+\epsilon\right) \leq e^{-\frac{1}{4}n\epsilon^2}$.

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification, central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers

$S_n = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} X_i$ where $X_i$'s are i.i.d RVs. $\mathbb{P}(X_i = 1) = p, \mathbb{P}(X_i = 0) = 1-p$. Prove that for any $\epsilon > 0$, $\mathbb{P} \left(\frac{S_n}{n} > p+\epsilon\right) \leq e^{\frac{1}{4}n\epsilon^2}$.

My proof is:

$\mathbb{E}(X_i) = p$, Var$(X)=p(1-p)$, both $< + \infty$.

By WLLN, $\forall \epsilon > 0$,$\mathbb{P} \left(\left|\frac{S_n}{n} - p\right| > \epsilon\right) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow + \infty$.

Then $\mathbb{P} \left(\frac{S_n}{n}> p+\epsilon\right)\rightarrow 0$.

Since $e^{\frac{1}{4}n\epsilon^2} \geq 0$, $\mathbb{P} \left(\frac{S_n}{n} > p+\epsilon\right) \leq e^{-\frac{1}{4}n\epsilon^2}$.

Am I right? Thank you so much!

Comment: No, that won't work. The limit being $0$ only tells you that for fixed $\epsilon>0$, the probability can be made as small as we want by taking $n$ large enough.

Comment: Then how should I prove it?

Comment: Possible strategy: $S_n$ is binomial.

Comment: The definition $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} X_i$ is problematic.  For one thing: The left-hand-side depends on $n$ while the right-hand-side does not.

Comment: By Hoeffding's inequality, $\mathbb{P} \left(\frac{S_n}{n} > p+\epsilon\right)\leq \exp(-2n\epsilon^2)$ which is certainly $\leq \exp(\frac{1}{4}n\epsilon^2)$

Comment: Are you sure the term on the RHS is $\displaystyle \exp \left( \frac{1}{4} n \epsilon^2 \right)$? Since $n, \epsilon$ > 0, $\frac{1}{4} n \epsilon^2  > 0$ and hence $ \displaystyle \exp \left( \frac{1}{4} n \epsilon^2 \right) > 1$ implying the expression is trivially true since probability is always atmost $1$. I think there should be a negative and then you can still use the Hoeffding's inequality as @GabrielRomon suggested to get the required answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that $$S_n \sim B(n,p)$$

Then:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(\frac{S_n}{n} \geq p + \epsilon) & \leq \sum_{k \geq n(p+\epsilon)} \binom{n}{k} p^k q^{n-k} \\  
\leq & \sum_{k \geq n(p+\epsilon)} e^{-\lambda((p+\epsilon)n - k)} \binom{n}{k} p^k q^{n-k} \\
\leq & e^{-\lambda n \epsilon} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (pe^{\lambda q})^k (qe^{-\lambda p})^{n-k} = \\
= & e^{-\lambda n \epsilon} (p e^{\lambda q} + q e^{-\lambda p})^n \leq \\
\leq & e^{-\lambda n \epsilon} ( pe^{\lambda^2 q^2} + q e^{\lambda^2 p^2})^n \leq \\
\leq & e^{-\lambda n \epsilon} e^{\frac{1}{8} \lambda^2 n}
\end{align*}

note that $(p+\epsilon)n - k < 0$, so first $\exp(\cdot)$ is always greater than one, therefore first inequality is true.

Second one: $e^{\lambda p(n-k) + \lambda k} = e^{-\lambda pn + \lambda pk - \lambda pk + \lambda k} = e^{-\lambda p(n-k)} e^{\lambda k (1-p)} = (e^{-\lambda q})^k (e^{-\lambda p})^{n-k}$. We use $a^k b^k = (ab)^k$ and then just add terms up to $k=0$. Everything is nonnegative, so we still have inequality

In second to last we use $e^x \leq x + e^{x^2}$ and $pe^{qx} + qe^{-px} \leq e^{\frac{1}{8} x^2}$

Now we pick $\lambda$ such that RHS is minimized, $\lambda = 4 \epsilon$

Comment: Thank you so much!!